SVG Texture Tiled Plane
Im trying to tile a plane in SVG, but unfortunatley i cant use css3 perspective as its buggy in safari. I tried skewX with a fixed perspective tile. It kind of works, but i think the maths is wrong? Has anyone experience with maths of tiling a plane in CSS?
I was hoping the mirror tiles would stay aligned but they don't seem to line up after 5 columns.


:root {
  --baseWidth: 97;
  --baseFactor: calc(5/8);
}

#sRows use:nth-child(even) {
  --f1: #ff0;
  --f2: #000;
  --col: var(--f1);
}

#sRows use:nth-child(odd) {
  --f1: #000;
  --f2: #ff0;
  --col: var(--f1);
}

#mCol use:nth-child(even) {
  --f: var(--f1);
}

#mCol use:nth-child(odd) {
  --f: var(--f2);
}

#mCol use {
  --x: calc(var(--baseWidth) * var(--i));
  --s: calc(89 - calc(30 / var(--i)));
}

#mCol use:first-child {
  --s: calc(91 - calc(30 / var(--i)));
}

#mirrorLeft {
  transform: skewX(calc( var(--s) * -1deg)) translate(calc(var(--x) * -1px));
}

#mirrorRight {
  transform: skewX(calc( var(--s) * 1deg)) translate(calc(var(--x) * 1px));
}

#sRows use {
  --rx: calc(240 - calc(204 * pow(var(--baseFactor), calc( var(--ri) + 1))));
  --ry: calc(88 + calc( 90 * pow( var(--baseFactor), var(--ri))));
  --rz: calc( var(--baseWidth) * pow(var(--baseFactor), var(--ri)));
  transform: translate(calc(var(--rx)*1px), calc( var(--ry) * 1px)) scale(calc(var(--rz)*1.66%));
}
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="480" height="180">
   <defs>
      <symbol id="tileTemplate" overflow="hidden" >
         <path style="fill:var(--f)" d="M 31.5 0 H 127.5 L 160 35 H 0 Z" opacity=".5" />
         <?ignore
         <g >
            <path style="fill:var(--f)" d="M 31.5 0 H 128.5 L 160 35 H 0 Z" opacity=".25"/>
            <g opacity=".5" >
               <path d="m 79 23.3471 l -0.208 11.433 m 30.182 -20.888 l 3.75 8.6 m -64.112 -8.6 l -4.063 8.6 m 100.9347 1.3838 l 9.1319 9.852 M 130 6.5311 l 6.003 7.031 M 79 6.5311 L 78.873 13.5621 m 24.23 -13.135 l 2.435 5.585 M 54.971 0.4271 L 52.333 6.0121" style="stroke:#fff;stroke-width:2"/>
               <path d="m 147.571,22.984 10.177,11 M 81,22.984 81.208,34.417 m 30.18,-20.888 4.063,8.6 m -64.425,-8.6 -3.75,8.6 m 85.327,-15.961 6.003,7.031 M 81,6.168 l 0.127,7.031 m 23.902,-13.135 2.638,5.585 M 56.897,0.064 54.462,5.649" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2" />
               <path d="m 0.665,33.984 h 158.67 M 11.44,22.554 H 148.56 M 20.063,13.2 H 140.189 M 26.6,5.907 h 106.88" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2"/>
            </g>
         </g>
         ?>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="tRow" overflow="visible">
         <use href="#tileTemplate" style="--f:var(--col)" />
         <use href="#mCol" />
      </symbol> 
      <symbol id="mSkew" overflow="visible" >
         <use id="mirrorRight" href="#tileTemplate"   />
         <use id="mirrorLeft"  href="#tileTemplate"  />
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="mCol" overflow="visible" >
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:1"  />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:2 " />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:3 " />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:4 " />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:5 " />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:6 " />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:7 " />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:8 " />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:9 " />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:10" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:11" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:12" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:13" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:14" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:15" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:16" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:17" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:18" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:19" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:20" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:21" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:22" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:23" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:24" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:25" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:26" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:27" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:28" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:29" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:30" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:31" />
         <use href="#mSkew" style="--i:32" />
      </symbol>  
   </defs>
   <g id="sRows" class="scaleRows" >
      <use href="#tRow" style="--ri:1;"/>
      <use href="#tRow" style="--ri:2;" />
      <use href="#tRow" style="--ri:3;" />
      <use href="#tRow" style="--ri:4;" />
      <use href="#tRow" style="--ri:5;" />
      <use href="#tRow" style="--ri:6;" />
      <use href="#tRow" style="--ri:7;" />
      <use href="#tRow" style="--ri:8;" />
   </g>
   <g transform="translate(240)" display="inline" opacity=".5" >
      <path d="M 0,0 -80,180 M 0,0 80,180" style="stroke:#888;stroke-width:0.5"/>
      <path d="M -240,145 H 240" style="stroke:#0f0;stroke-width:.5;stroke-dasharray:1, 1" />
      <path d="M 0,90 -80,180 M 0,90 80,180" style="stroke:#00f;stroke-width:.5;stroke-dasharray:1, 1"  />
   </g>
</svg>




An alternative to consider is to do one giant shape filled with a yellow/gray pattern and use CSS perspective on the outer SVG element (which should work).

Sorry unfortunately that won't work with safari when svg set to image src, canvas or webgl. It much simpler in chrome.

To make your computations as easy as possible, your focal point should be at [0, 0] of the user coordinate system. Then, after you draw a base tile, two characteristic numbers are needed:
--width: x distance between the two lower corners / y value of the lower corners
--height: y value of the upper corners / y value of the lower corners

For my example, I've choosen them to be 0.2 and 0.9, respectively.
Then, the skewed tiles of each row can be computed as
transform: skewX(atan(var(--width) * [0, 1, 2,...]));

and the scaling of each row as
transform: scale(pow(var(--height), [0, 1, 2,...]));

Instead of explicite mirroring, you can just add negative numbers to continue in the opposite direction from the base tile. This is both true for horizontal and vertical tiling.


:root {
  --width: 0.2;
  --height: 0.9;
}

use[href="#tile"] {
  fill: none;
  transform: skewX(atan(var(--width, 0) * var(--x)));
}

use[href="#row"] {
  transform: scale(pow(var(--height), var(--y)));
}

use[href="#row"]:nth-child(even) {
  --even: red;
  --odd: darkgreen;
}

use[href="#row"]:nth-child(odd) {
  --even: darkgreen;
  --odd: red;
}

use[href="#tile"]:nth-child(even) {
  stroke: var(--even);
}

use[href="#tile"]:nth-child(odd) {
  stroke: var(--odd);
}

use#base {
  stroke: black;
}
<svg viewBox="-100 50 200 100">
  <defs>
    <path id="tile" d="M -9.4,90 H 8.6 M -9.25,92.4 H 8.75 L 9,94.8 M -9.5,94.8 H 9.5 M -9.75,97.4 H 9.25 L 9.5,100 M -4.5,90 -4.625,92.4 M -4.75,94.8 -4.875,97.4 M 4.5,90 4.625,92.5 M 4.75,94.8 4.875,97.4 M 0,92.5 V 94.8 M 0,97.4 V 99.5"/>
    <g id="row">
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:-10"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:-9"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:-8"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:-7"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:-6"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:-5"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:-4"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:-3"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:-2"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:-1"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:0"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:1"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:2"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:3"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:4"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:5"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:6"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:7"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:8"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:9"/>
      <use href="#tile" style="--x:10"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <use href="#row" style="--y:-4"/>
  <use href="#row" style="--y:-3"/>
  <use href="#row" style="--y:-2"/>
  <use href="#row" style="--y:-1"/>
  <use href="#row" style="--y:0"/>
  <use href="#row" style="--y:1"/>
  <use href="#row" style="--y:2"/>
  <use href="#row" style="--y:3"/>
  <use href="#row" style="--y:4"/>
  <use href="#row" style="--y:5"/>
  <use href="#row" style="--y:6"/>
  <use href="#row" style="--y:7"/>
  <use href="#row" style="--y:8"/>
  <!-- repeat the base tile just to mark its position -->
  <use id="base" href="#tile"/>
</svg>




This is perfect and simplifies the layout. I'd mark this as answered or even up vote but the don't the reputation yet. Separate question: Is there any way to use css counters rather than explicit var style assignments on elements?

nope, that doesn't work. counter() returns a string, and type casting is not supported in CSS. – You should be able to accept an answer regardless of reputation.

I figured out the mark as answered, it was a gray tick. Hard to see on mobile. Thanks again
